# Best airbrushing plugin?

Tags: software, post-processing, photoshop

What is the best airbrushing plugin besides Kodak Digital GEM Airbrush Pro and Portraiture?

I the kodak plugin to cleanup skin and textures, but they're apparently not going to upgrade for CS5/Mac/64bit (yes, and I don't want to run photoshop in 32bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there is Topaz Clean by Topaz Labs. Cheaper, supports CS5 64bit and it can also add texture. The airbrushing, however is not as good as the Kodak's, but since it's used only with a small opacity, it will do.